# OpenGL ES 2.0: Adding EGL_DEPTH_SIZE into an existing EGL context

Tags: opengl-es, depth, egl

I'm working on some OGLES2 code which is using a context set up by some framework software *(to which I have no access)*, and I'm trying to draw a simple cube.

Having ended up with just a flat square moving around the screen, I investigated the current rendering context's configuration and it turns out that `EGL_DEPTH_SIZE` is set to `0`, so the `z` value of all my vertices is being ignored.

I need to operate within the context of the framework because I am using some textures that they are providing *(to map onto my cube faces)* so I really need to know, is there any way to re-enable a depth buffer for this context? Failing that are there any workarounds *(ie. could I render to a VBO or would that also ignore all my `z` values)*?